# QSsh: SshConnection

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qt-creator

I want to create a Ssh connection using QSsh. 
When i execute the following code, i've got an error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Botan::Invalid_State'
  what():  Could not find a thread-safe mutex object to use

Does anyone have any idea please? :)

```
QSsh::SshConnectionParameters params;
params.host = host;
params.userName = username;
params.password = passwd;
params.authenticationType =QSsh::SshConnectionParameters::AuthenticationTypePassword;
params.timeout = 30;
params.port = 22;

QSsh::SshConnection * m_connection = new QSsh::SshConnection(params, this);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: i have no idea on you actual problem, but you do not need to `delete m_connection`. it is done using `Qt`'s way of garbage collection, when `this` gets destroyed, it will destroy all its children